# How to copy an image from a folder temporarily and delete it afterwards in PHP?

Tags: php, image, copy

I have a folder on a NAS containing several images.
I would like to make a local copy of the images in a folder, display the images and then delete them so that they don't take over the local on the server.

How can I delete the photos after viewing them?

I made this code but it deletes the following image, so it can't be displayed :

```
<?php
$file = '//Alcyons/it/PhotoShoot/Photos_Outil/A1111_0070_1.jpg';
$newfile = 'A1111_0070_1.jpg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "La copie $file du fichier a échoué...\n";
}

echo "</td><td valign=top align=center><img src=\"$newfile\" border=0 width=180px></a></td><td width=10></td>";


unlink($newfile);

?>
```

Comment: _“and once the script execution finishes deleting them”_ - when my browser will actually requests these images, has little to do with when your script finished.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: _“How can I delete the photos after viewing them?”_ - well how would you know, _that_ they have been viewed? Unless you want to start digging through your web server’s access logs in some automated fashion, you would need to come up with some mechanism to figure that one out first of all.

Comment: But after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736737, it still rather seems like you are approaching this from a completely wrong angle. So you are saying you can’t manage to find a setup where you could embed this location directly via the web server, via an Alias or something like that - but you _can_ read the files directly using PHP? That doesn’t appear to make too much sense to begin with.

Comment: I can read all the files on the NAS but I can't display the pictures just. That's why I want to make a local copy of them temporarily, display them and then delete them so that they don't take up all the space.

Comment: If PHP running via your web server can read the files to be able to copy them, then your webserver itself should also be able to read from that location. What Adyson commented last on your previous question, is from all we know so far probably still the _proper_ way to achieve this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736737/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-folder-on-a-nas-in-php#comment107461490_60736737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you solve by copying the file?

How does it make sense if you delete it instantly?

According to your code structure, that one will be better:

```
<?php

$file = '//Alcyons/it/PhotoShoot/Photos_Outil/A1111_0070_1.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

?>
</td>
<td valign=top align=center>
  <img src="<?php echo "data:image/$type;base64,",
     base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)) ?>" border=0 width="180"></a>
</td>
<td width=10></td>
```

Comment: And even better it would make an alias in Apache / Nginx config.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem! I can finally display my photo in my NAS folder.

Comment: I'll test with this method and if not, I'll see if I can make an alias.